# Using open database connection to PostgreSQL in BASH?

Tags: bash, postgresql, named-pipes, postgresql-9.1

I have to use BASH to connect to our PostgreSQL 9.1 database server to execute various SQL statements.

We have a performance issue caused by repeatedly opening/closing too many database connections (right now, we send each statement to a psql command).

I am looking at the possibility of maintaining an open database connection for a block of SQL statements using named pipes.

The problem I have is that once I open a connection and execute a SQL statement, I don't know when to stop reading from the psql. I've thought about parsing the output to look for a prompt, although I don't know if that is safe considering the possibility that the character may be embedded in a SELECT output.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Here's a simplified example of what I have thus far...

```
#!/bin/bash

PIPE_IN=/tmp/pipe.in
PIPE_OUT=/tmp/pipe.out

mkfifo $PIPE_IN $PIPE_OUT
psql -A -t jkim_edr_md_xxx_db < $PIPE_IN > $PIPE_OUT &
exec 5> $PIPE_IN; rm -f $PIPE_IN
exec 4< $PIPE_OUT; rm -f $PIPE_OUT

echo 'SELECT * FROM some_table' >&5

# unfortunately, this loop blocks
while read -u 4 LINE
do
    echo LINE=$LINE
done
```

Comment: PostgreSQL supports persistent connections. You don't need to open and close connections all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`--file=filename`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) for a batch execution.

Depending on your need for flow control you may want to use another language with a more flexible DB API (Python would be my choice here but use whatever works).

Comment: I need to process the results from the SQL statements individually so I don't think batch execution will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
            echo >&5 "SELECT * FROM some_table"
```

should read

```
            echo 'SELECT * FROM some_table' >&5
```

The redirection operator `>&` comes after the parameters to `echo`; and also, if you use `""` quotes, some punctuation may be treated specially by the shell, causing foul and mysterious bugs later. On the other hand, quoting `'` will be … ugly. `SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE foo=\'Can\'\'t read\''` …

You probably want to also create these pipes someplace safer than `/tmp`. There's a big security-hole race condition where someone else on host could hijack your connection. Try creating a folder like `/var/run/yournamehere/` with `0700` privileges, and create the pipes there, ideally with names like `PIPE_IN=/var/run/jinkimsqltool/sql.pipe.in.$$` — `$$` will be your process ID, so simulataneously-executed scripts won't clobber one another. (To exacerbate the security hole, `rm -rf` should not be needed for a pipe, but a clever cracker could use that excalation of privileges to abuse the `-r` there. Just `rm -f` is sufficient.)

Comment: Thanks I have updated my post with some of your recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

in psql You can use

```
\o YOUR_PIPE
SELECT whatever;
\o
```

which will open, write and close the pipe. Your BASH-fu seems quite a lot stronger than mine, so I'll let You work out the details :)